# how does reference an associative array variable by the value of a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have three  associative arrays:

```
declare -A start_obj end_obj gopath

start_obj['one']="start-obj-one"
start_obj['two']="start-obj-two"

end_obj['one']="end-obj-one"
end_obj['two']="end-obj-two"

gopath['start']="/path/to/start"
gopath['end']="/path/to/end"
```

I want to get the key and value of `start_obj`, `end_obj` arrays by the key of the `gopath` array, code show as below:

```
for t in "${!gopath[@]}"
do
    current=$t"_obj"[@]
    cd ${gopath[$t]}
    for k in ${!current}
    do    
        printf  "[$t]key is : $k ; value is : ${current[$k]}\n"                                                           
    done
done
```

But , the result of this code execution is :

```
[start]key is : start-obj-one ; value is : start_obj[@]
[start]key is : start-obj-two ; value is : start_obj[@]
[end]key is : end-obj-one ; value is : end_obj[@]
[end]key is : end-obj-two ; value is : end_obj[@]
```

The result I expect is:

```
[start]key is : one ; value is : start-obj-one
[start]key is : two ; value is : start-obj-two
[end]key is : one ; value is : end-obj-one
[end]key is : two ; value is : end-obj-two
```

So，how should I modify my code to get the results I expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash` 4.3 or newer, you could use nameref variables:

```
for t in "${!gopath[@]}"; do
  (
    typeset -n current="${t}_obj"
    cd -P -- "${gopath[$t]}" || exit
    for k in "${!current[@]}"
    do    
      printf '%s\n' "[$t]key is: $k; value is: ${current[$k]}"
    done
  )
done
```

With older versions, you'd need to use `eval`:

```
for t in "${!gopath[@]}"; do
  (
    cd -P -- "${gopath[$t]}" || exit
    eval '
      for k in "${!'"$t"'_obj[@]}"
      do    
        printf "%s\n" "[$t]key is: $k; value is: ${'"$t"'_obj[$k]}"
      done
    '
  )
done
```

`bash` has a variable indirection operator: `${!varname}`, unrelated to the `${!hash[@]}` operator (and actually closer to the reverse of what `${!varname}` is in ksh93), but it cannot be combined with the `${!hash[@]}` operator (`varname=hash; for key in "${!!varname[@]}"...` won't work). For a shell with a usable variable indirection operator here (and that has supported associative arrays for much longer), you can look at `zsh` (using `${(P)varname}`) which also lets you loop over both key  and value at the same time:

```
typeset -A start_obj end_obj gopath
start_obj=(
  one  start-obj-one
  two  start-obj-two
)
end_obj=(
  one  end-obj-one
  two  end-obj-two
)
gopath=(
  start  /path/to/start
  end    /path/to/end
)
for t dir ("${(kv@)gopath}") (
  cd -P -- "$dir" || exit
  current=${t}_obj
  for key value ("${(kvP@)current}")
    printf '%s\n' "[$t]key is: $key; value is: $value}"
)
```

In any case, in both `bash` and `zsh` (and `ksh93` the first shell that introduced associative arrays and that `bash` tried to copy), associative arrays are implemented as hash tables, so the elements are not stored in any particular order, so those code above will loop over them in a seemingly random order.

Comment: Thanks , my bash version is  4.2.46(2)-release  ,I got an error: "typeset: -n: invalid option" .It seems that it does not support "typeset -n".

Comment: @shaun, see edit.

Comment: The code you append is not work., i got the resule : "[start]key is : one ; value is : " , value  is null .  But, i know your thoughts.  Thanks.

Comment: @shaun, yes sorry, I had forgotten to replace the second occurrence of `current`. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

With earlier bash versions, you can do this with *indexed* arrays, but not with associative arrays, using variable indirection:

```
$ declare -p start_obj end_obj gopath
declare -A start_obj='([one]="start-obj-one" [two]="start-obj-two" )'
declare -A end_obj='([one]="end-obj-one" [two]="end-obj-two" )'
declare -A gopath='([start]="/path/to/start" [end]="/path/to/end" )'

$ for t in "${!gopath[@]}"; do tmp="${t}_obj[@]"; ary=( "${!tmp}" ); declare -p ary; done
declare -a ary='([0]="start-obj-one" [1]="start-obj-two")'
declare -a ary='([0]="end-obj-one" [1]="end-obj-two")'
```

Note how we can get the *values* but not the *keys* of the associative arrays.

For more info, see the 4th paragraph in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion